# Loop through url with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The below `request` finds the contest id's for the day. I am trying to pass that `str` into the `driver.get` `url` so it will go to each individual contest `url` and download each contests `CSV`. I would imagine you have to write a `loop` but I'm not sure what that would look like with a `webdriver`.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import datetime

req = requests.get('https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getlivecontests?sport=NBA') 
data = req.json()

for ids in data:
    contest = ids['id']

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.draftkings.com/account/sitelogin/false?returnurl=%2Flobby');
time.sleep(2) # Let DK Load!

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
search_box.send_keys('username')
search_box2 = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
search_box2.send_keys('password')
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-mobile-home"]/section/section[2]/div[3]/button/span')
submit_button.click()
time.sleep(2) # Let Page Load, If not it will go to Account!


driver.get('https://www.draftkings.com/contest/exportfullstandingscsv/' + str(contest) + '')
```

Comment: You can use dataprovider in testNG framework

Comment: so are these ids returned in the url? is it that sports=nba bit?

Comment: It will go through and grab all contest ids that are currently going. With those id's i would like it to go through and go to each contest via the ids and export the csv

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson can you show HTML of the landing page after you've signed-in? I have a solution for this but I need the HTML.

Comment: Cant really copy all of it. You can log in and see if you'd like. username Pr0c3ss, pw: generic1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in following order:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import datetime

req = requests.get('https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getlivecontests?sport=NBA')
data = req.json()



driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.draftkings.com/account/sitelogin/false?returnurl=%2Flobby')
time.sleep(2) # Let DK Load!

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
search_box.send_keys('Pr0c3ss')
search_box2 = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
search_box2.send_keys('generic1!')
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-mobile-home"]/section/section[2]/div[3]/button/span')
submit_button.click()
time.sleep(2) # Let Page Load, If not it will go to Account!

for ids in data:
    contest = ids['id']
    driver.get('https://www.draftkings.com/contest/exportfullstandingscsv/' + str(contest) + '')
```

Comment: It looks like it works, ill have to check it tonight once contests are going. nice work!

Comment: don't use static sleep

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to send load selenium for x nos of times to download x nos of files. Requests and selenium can share cookies. This means you can login to site with selenium, retrieve the login details and share them with requests or any other application. *Take a moment to check out httpie, https://httpie.org/doc#sessions it seems you manually control sessions like requests does.*

For requests look at: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=sessions
For selenium look at: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#cookies

Looking at the Webdriver block,you can add proxies and load the browser headless or live: Just comment the headless line and it should load the browser live, this makes debugging easy, easy to understand movements and changes to site api/html.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import requests
import datetime
import shutil



LOGIN = 'https://www.draftkings.com/account/sitelogin/false?returnurl=%2Flobby'
BASE_URL = 'https://www.draftkings.com/contest/exportfullstandingscsv/'
USER = ''
PASS = ''

try:
    data = requests.get('https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getlivecontests?sport=NBA').json()
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)
    exit()


ids = [str(item['id']) for item in data]

# Webdriver block
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=800x600')
# options.add_argument('--proxy-server= IP:PORT')
# options.add_argument('--user-agent=' + USER_AGENT)

try:
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
except WebDriverException:
    exit()

def login(USER, PASS)
    '''
    Login to draftkings.
    Retrieve authentication/authorization.

    http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits
    http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.common.exceptions

    '''

    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    search_box.send_keys(USER)

    search_box2 = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    search_box2.send_keys(PASS)

    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-mobile-home"]/section/section[2]/div[3]/button/span')
    submit_button.click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    return cookies


site_cookies = login(USER, PASS)

def get_csv_files(id):
    '''
    get each id and download the file.
    '''

    session = rq.session()

    for cookie in site_cookies:
        session.cookies.update(cookies)

    try:
        _data = session.get(BASE_URL + id)
        with open(id + '.csv', 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(data.raw, f)
    except BaseException:
        return


map(get_csv_files, ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

will this help

```
for ids in data:
    contest = ids['id']
    driver.get('https://www.draftkings.com/contest/exportfullstandingscsv/' + str(contest) + '')
```

Comment: what happens to it?

Answer (score 0):

May be its time to decompose it a bit.
Create few isolated functions, which are:
 0. (optional) Provide authorisation to target url.
 1. Collecting all needed `id` (first part of your code).
 2. Exporting CSV for specific `id` (second part of your code).
 3. Loop through list of `id` and call func #2 for each.

Share `chromedriver` as input argument for each of them to save driver state and auth-cookies.
Its works fine, make code clear and readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the URL of a contest to an `a` element in the landing page, and then click on it. Then repeat the step with other ID.

See my code below.

```
req = requests.get('https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getlivecontests?sport=NBA') 
data = req.json()
contests = []

for ids in data:
    contests.append(ids['id'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.draftkings.com/account/sitelogin/false?returnurl=%2Flobby');
time.sleep(2) # Let DK Load!

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
search_box.send_keys('username')
search_box2 = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
search_box2.send_keys('password')
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-mobile-home"]/section/section[2]/div[3]/button/span')
submit_button.click()
time.sleep(2) # Let Page Load, If not it will go to Account!

for id in contests:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a')
    script1 = "arguments[0].setAttribute('download',arguments[1]);"
    driver.execute_script(script1, element, str(id) + '.pdf')
    script2 = "arguments[0].setAttribute('href',arguments[1]);"
    driver.execute_script(script2, element, 'https://www.draftkings.com/contest/exportfullstandingscsv/' + str(id))
    time.sleep(1)
    element.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```